# Приоритетность выполнения операций java

Tags: java, циклы, потоки-данных, синхронизация

В теле `main` запускаю цикл (на 50 итераций), в теле которого вывод текста на экран и вброс команд в поток. При компиляции выводит сперва 50 строк текста на экран, а потом только начинает работать с потоками. 
Пример:

```
PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(cmd_proc.getOutputStream());
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {  
    System.out.println(i); 
    stdin.println(comand_execute); //посылаем команды в консоль
    stdin.flush(); 
}
```

На выходе получаю: "1,2,3,...50", а потом(секунды через 3) выполняются последовательно команды посылаемые в поток.

Как добиться "правильного" (последовательного) выполнения операций?
(1-команда, 2-команда, 3-команда,....50-команда)

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Лучше делать так.

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("host -t a " + domain);
   p.waitFor();
```

Тогда и вывод команд перехватить можно.